# How to fix particle board at lock screw (Ikea Effektiv)

Tags: wood, cabinets, particle-board

What is the right way to fix the particle board around the lock screw of an Ikea Effektiv full size cabinet? The movers seem to have dropped one end and essentially the wood around three of the lock screws has broken:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90044489/IMG_20150215_103144.jpg]

Do I attempt to fix this with wood glue, wood nails or duct tape?

Comment: If you hired professional movers you have them buy you a new cabinet, on their dime. They should have insurance for damages. As for trying to fix broken particle-board - good luck with that, you'll need it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Lawrence on this, where there is blame, there is a claim. If you want to have a go at fixing however then go to a ships chandler and get a good glue from them. However, the trick is to clamp the pieces tight. I don't mean but some books on it but use something that has a vice-like grip spread over 3 or 4 inches. All that said, if this is an area not seen when draws/doors are closed then "No-Nails" type compound will suffice. Good luck